# Can I use an iTextSharp cell event to repeat data on the next page when a row is split?

Tags: vb.net, events, pdf-generation, itext

I have a very deep row in a pdfptable. The columns in the left-hand side of this row contain a sub table which has many rows within it. I would like the deep row to split onto more than one page if it is too deep to fit on one page. I can set SplitLate to false to ensure that the row splits. However, the data for the deep columns on the right hand side only shows on the first page and I would like it to be repeated on the second page.

A bit of investigation suggested that I could use a cell event to put the text into the cells and have it repeated on the second page. So I created a cell event as follows:

```
Public Class PdfPCellEvent
Implements iTextSharp.text.pdf.IPdfPCellEvent

Private m_text As String
Private m_font As text.pdf.BaseFont

Public Sub New(ByVal text As String, font As text.pdf.BaseFont)
    MyBase.New()

    m_text = text
    m_font = font

End Sub

Public Sub CellLayout(cell As PdfPCell, position As text.Rectangle, canvases() As PdfContentByte) Implements IPdfPCellEvent.CellLayout

    Dim cb As PdfContentByte = canvases(PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS)
    cb.BeginText()
    cb.SetFontAndSize(m_font, 8)
    cb.ShowText(m_text)
    cb.EndText()

End Sub

End Class
```

I then call this as follows:

```
Dim cell As PdfPCell = New PdfPCell()
Dim bfReport As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, False)

Dim cellEvent As New PdfPCellEvent("Text", bfReport)
cell.CellEvent = cellEvent
mainTable.AddCell(cell)

document.Add(mainTable)
```

This all runs. I can see that the cell event is being called twice after the mainTable is added to the document. I presume it is being called once for each page the row appears on. I can also see that the correct text is being passed into CellLayout. However no text appears in the resulting pdf. What am I doing wrong? I have tried various ways of adding the text in CellLayout but none have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something missing in this code snippet:

```
Dim cb As PdfContentByte = canvases(PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS)
cb.BeginText()
cb.SetFontAndSize(m_font, 8)
cb.ShowText(m_text)
cb.EndText()
```

You are creating a text block, but you forget to specify coordinates. I suspect that the `BT`/`ET` sequence is added to the content stream, but there's no way of telling where the text will show up on the page.

In the cell layout, you have access to `position As text.Rectangle`. You can ask the `position` variable for coordinates. You can use these coordinates in the code snippet about (using the `SetTextMatrix()` method), but it will be easier for you if you *don't use* `cb.BeginText(), cb.SetFontAndSize(), cb.SetTextMatrix(), cb.ShowText(), cb.EndText()`. Use `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned()` instead. You can pass the `cb` instance as a parameter, along with a `Phrase`, an alignment (left, right, center), an X,Y coordinate and an angle.

Comment: Thanks, I've got this working now and have added the corrected code below.

Comment: Great that you added an answer with the working code!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, the following now works perfectly:

```
Public Class PdfPCellEvent
Implements iTextSharp.text.pdf.IPdfPCellEvent

Private m_phrase As text.Phrase

Public Sub New(ByVal phrase As text.Phrase)
    MyBase.New()

    m_phrase = phrase

End Sub

Public Sub CellLayout(cell As PdfPCell, position As text.Rectangle, canvases() As PdfContentByte) Implements IPdfPCellEvent.CellLayout

    Dim cb As PdfContentByte = canvases(PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS)
    Dim CenterX As Single = position.GetLeft(0) + (position.Width() / 2)
    Dim CenterY As Single = position.GetBottom(0) + (position.Height() / 2)
    ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER, m_phrase, CenterX, CenterY, 0)

End Sub

End Class
```

And I call this as follows:

```
phrase = New text.Phrase("Text", fontSmaller)
Dim cell As PdfPCell = New PdfPCell()
Dim cellEvent As New PdfPCellEvent(phrase)
cell.CellEvent = cellEvent
mainTable.AddCell(cell)
document.Add(mainTable)
```

The text now appears on both pages and is centred vertically and horizontally in the cell.